# Publishing Website

Tags: image, get, project, publish

When we publish web application, images store in physical folder are not displaying on actual runtime. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Httpwatch is an excellent tool which I use for diagnosing these kinds of problems. There is a free and a paid for version.

Answer (score 0):

Check if HTTP requests are being sent for the images, and if they are sent to the correct address. If they are, check your web server logs to identify where those requests end up, and whether the files themselves are present in the right location with appropriate read permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the images with a relative path rather than the fully qualified path.

```
<image src="../images/test.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the images with Full HTTP Path or relative path or absolute path but they have to be correct to be able to show images.

Make sure that you do not have "file:\C:.....\test.png" as IMG SRC.